# django foreign key Cannot assign must be a instance

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

I am developing a web app using Django. I have created the table in MySQL database and then generated the models.py using inspectdb. I am able to fetch details and connect to the database without any issues. But while saving the values to the particular table, below error is shown

```
sav_list = List(id=4, item_name ='name1', item_desc='desc1', location='location', reason='rfp',  pid=3)
```

Cannot assign "3": "List.id" must be a "Order" instance.

my models

```
class List(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    item_name = models.CharField(db_column='Item_Name', max_length=255)  # Field name made lowercase.
    item_desc = models.CharField(db_column='Item_Desc', max_length=300)  # Field name made lowercase.
    location = models.CharField(db_column='Location', max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    reason = models.CharField(db_column='Reason', max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    pid = models.ForeignKey('Order', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='PID')  # Field name made lowercase.

class Order(models.Model):
    poid = models.IntegerField(db_column='POID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    po = models.CharField(db_column='PO', unique=True, max_length=20)  # Field name made lowercase.
    quote = models.CharField(db_column='Quote', unique=True, max_length=20)  # Field name made lowercase.
    condition = models.CharField(db_column='Condition', max_length=15)  # Field name made lowercase.
```

I have tried relate_name for foreign key but still same behaviour. Same values can be stored on database without any issues. Only Django throws an error.

Please someone help me!!!

Comment: try `pid_id` as it's related field

Comment: The typical ways of development with Django is to create the model and let Django's migrations handle the creation and alteration of the database. Also Django creates a primary key on its own, so there is usually no need to create one manually.

Comment: Thanks @ThatBird. It worked.

Answer (score 5):

You should paste the actual error; it is presumably that "List.**pid**" must be an "Order" instance.

The error should be clear. `pid` is a ForeignKey field, it expects an instance of the related model. You can either get the item and set it:

```
pid = Order.objects.get(pk=3)
List(...., pid=pid)
```

or use the underlying id field:

```
List(...., pid_id=3)
```

Comment: Sorry for not pasting the right error. Thanks a lot for your help. It worked. I have changed it to PID_ID.  Simple mistake..

Answer (score 1):

The `pid` column at the *Django* level is not an `id` (integer), yes on the database level it is. But in Django it is a foreign key, and thus it refers to an `Order` instance. You thus should pass it an `Order` instance (the one that corresponds to `poid=3`).

But we are lucky, in case you construct such `ForeignKey`, Django automatically makes a `field_id` column that stores the id, and those two fields act like twins. We can thus assign `3` to `pid_id`:

```
sav_list = List(
    id=4,
    item_name ='name1',
    item_desc='desc1',
    location='location', reason='rfp',
    pid_id=3
)
```

Note however that for most database backend, *foreign key constraints* will check if there is an `Order` instance with as referenced column (in Django the primary key) `3` exists. If not, it is impossible to create such `List`. I would therefore advice to ensure that such `Order` exists before trying to save it to the database.

Comment: Thanks I used model_id instead of model and it works in migrations. I know models are particular when you are in a migration and you are getting them from state, so this must be the trick to save them.